# Prevent repeating row field value to the next row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query that is supposed to join different types of bonuses of users from different tables and sum up the bonuses on a weekly basis. The total amount for the different types of bonuses is been handled fine but the issue is that I'm having values carried to the next when a user has not earned any bonus.

Here is how my query looks like:

```
$bonuses =DB::table('users as u')
      ->select(
        'u.id',
        'u.referral',
        'packages.name as package_name',
        'shoppings.week_number as shopping_week',
        'performances.week_number as performance_week',
        'spillovers.week_number as spillover_week',
        'leaderships.week_number as leadership_week',
        DB::raw("CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) AS full_name"),
        DB::raw('ifnull(sum(shoppings.amount),0) as shopping_amount'),
        DB::raw('ifnull(sum(performances.amount),0) as performance_amount'),
        DB::raw('ifnull(sum(spillovers.amount),0) as spillover_amount'),
        DB::raw('ifnull(sum(leaderships.amount),0) as leadership_amount'),
        DB::raw("ifnull(sum(shoppings.amount),0) +
        ifnull(sum(performances.amount),0) +
        ifnull(sum(spillovers.amount),0) +
        ifnull(sum(leaderships
        .amount),0)
        as total"),
      )
      ->leftJoin('packages', 'u.package_id', '=', 'packages.id')
      ->leftJoin('shoppings', 'u.id', '=', 'shoppings.user_id')
      ->leftJoin('performances', 'u.id', '=', 'performances.user_id')
      ->leftJoin('spillovers', 'u.id', '=', 'spillovers.user_id')
      ->leftJoin('leaderships', 'u.id', '=', 'leaderships.user_id')
      ->groupBy('shopping_week', 'performance_week', 'spillover_week', 'leadership_week')
      ->get();
    return $bonuses;
```

[image: Here] is a screenshot to show how it is rendered. The circled field is supposed to be `0` but is taking the value of the previous row.

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Schema for the tables I joined:

```
public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('shoppings', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->float('amount', 10, 2)->default(0);
      $table->boolean('paid')->default(0);
      $table->foreignId('user_id');
      $table->foreignId('downline_id');
      $table->integer('week_number')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }


public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('performances', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->float('amount', 10, 2)->default(0);
      $table->boolean('paid')->default(0);
      $table->foreignId('user_id');
      $table->foreignId('downline_id');
      $table->integer('week_number')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('spillovers', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->float('amount', 10, 2)->default(0);
      $table->boolean('paid')->default(0);
      $table->foreignId('user_id');
      $table->foreignId('downline_id');
      $table->integer('week_number')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('leaderships', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->float('amount', 10, 2)->default(0);
      $table->boolean('paid')->default(0);
      $table->foreignId('user_id');
      $table->foreignId('downline_id');
      $table->integer('week_number')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }
```

Comment: even when your laravel query is straight forward, without a [mre] we can't see which tables have a 1: n relationshipt,which cause this behaviour.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql